# Why does the Generic List AddRange return void instead of a list?

Tags: c#

```
namespace System.Collections.Generic
  public List<T>    
    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> collection)
```

It seems like it might be an intentional design decision not to return something. I got bitten by this expecting AddRange to be "fluent."

I was just curious if anyone knew of the design motivations, if there were any, to return nothing?

Comment: out of curiosity: what would you want it to return?

Comment: A new List<T> with all items (Avoiding mutation of the original list) or the original List<T> with the items appended.

Comment: @JaneDoe based on the text, the final line of the method would be: `return this;`, and that's the only change to the original code he'd need.

Comment: @JoshuaEnfield: you're describing the .Concat() method here

Comment: @d--b true, except `Concat` does not modify the first collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other answers are (essentially) correct, but none of them addresses both possibilities for *why* `AddRange` might return something.

One reason for doing that would be to create a fluent API, like this:

```
list.Add(1).Add(2).Add(3);
list.AddRange(aGroupOfNumbers).AddRange(theNextGroupOfNumbers);
```

To achieve this, the list simply returns itself at the end of the method that mutates the list.  As Trisped notes, `StringBuilder` was doing this before the generic `List<T>` was introduced.

Another reason to return something, as Felix K. implies, is that the type is immutable.  If a list is immutable, it *can't* return itself at the end of the method, because it can't mutate itself; and it can't return void, again, because it can't mutate itself.  To reflect the change defined by the method contract, the list has to create a new instance that incorporates the change, and then, of course, it has to return that new instance to the caller.  People sometimes have a hard time conceiving of that when it comes to collections, but there's a very well-known type that behaves this way: `System.String`.  As d-b says, nobody expected the list to return anything, because the "classic" imperative programming style uses void methods when mutating data structures.

The designers of the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace may not have thought of giving their types a fluent API, but if they did, I could see how they might have decided against it.  Certainly, the case for a fluent API in StringBuilder is somewhat stronger than the case for a fluent API in `List<T>`.

Answer (score 31):

The `AddRange` method was added in .NET 2.0, before LINQ was out, and when "fluency" really wasn't in fashion at all. At the time, no one expected `AddRange` to return anything. Plus, in that version of .NET, there was no initializer for List object, so you **had** to Add() a bunch of items to the list. The AddRange provided a shortcut for not having to loop through and Add objects one by one.

The equivalent LINQ method is `IEnumerable<T>.Concat()`

Comment: Good answer, but not entirely correct.  Note that the AddRange method was added in .NET 2.0 because the entire *class* was added in 2.0.  The generic `List<T>` has had an constructor with an `IEnumerable<T>` parameter since it was released (I presume that's what you mean by "initializer"); the value of `AddRange` is that it allows you to add sequences of items at any time, not just on construction.  Also, there are instances of fluent APIs even earlier than .NET 2.0; `StringBuilder` comes to mind, as Trisped notes.

Answer (score 2):

The list is not a struct so it mutates, if you want a list which avoids mutation you have to write your own or use Linq or just use this code:

```
List<T> newList = new List<T>(originalList);
newList.AddRange(...);
```

Or use Linq when constructing the list( `IEnumerable<T>.Concat()` at the constructor ). There are many ways to avoid mutation.

Comment: Note that mutability independent of value-typeness; value types can be mutable or immutable, and reference types can be mutable or immutable.

Comment: @phoog This is correct, but usually the most value types are immutable and the most classes are muteable.

Answer (score 1):

The [`AddRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx) method adds `collection` to the [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) instance which called the function.

As a result you do not need to return anything, as the results are already there.

At the time if the work to be done did not create a new object then nothing was returned.  The only exceptions which comes to mind is  the [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) class where most of the member methods which return a pointer to the calling instance.  This was to enable command chaining and is specifically mentioned in the documentation.